# Vim Ruby syntax

Tags: ruby, vim

I am on Lubuntu and I am coding in ruby and I cant make the ruby syntax coloring work.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

It is kinda ok for me but the comments are not highlighted correctly. (anybody knows at least how to change that?)

In my /.~vim/bundle/ I got this:
`AutoComplPop  vim-bundler  vim-rails  vim-ruby`

And vim-ruby is reffering to this: https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby (I don't know if I installed it correctly, just pasted it there).

What do you you use for ruby syntax? I am using LXTerminal and Lubuntu btw.

Comment: What exactly does not work; i.e. what color / syntax group is it and what do you expect?

Comment: You've already linked to the GitHub project - why don't you just open an issue there?!

Comment: I think this is just how your current color scheme highlights comments in general. Try a different one, I personally prefer `:colors darkblue`, but there are many others in the default Vim distribution (check `$VIMRUNTIME/colors` for the full list), and you can always make your own.

Comment: :colors darkblue < should go in the vimrc file right?

Comment: @TestTest: Yes, to change your default color scheme, put `colors darkblue` (or whatever color scheme you end up picking) in your vimrc file. If you confirm that this was indeed the problem, I'll post it as a proper answer.

Comment: @TestTest Could you let Michael Madsen know if this solved your problem. That way he will post it in an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colors of comments to whatever you like (in addition to trying a different color scheme as suggested).  For example, this is particularly ugly:

```
:highlight rubyComment ctermfg=red ctermbg=green
```

And will likely show up differently than everything else in your color scheme.

Also note that some people comment using documentation such as:

```
=begin
Some documentation..
=end
```

The syntax highlight for this is rubyDocumentation.  There is also a 'rubyMultilineComment' but I'm not sure what that is for.